# Cannot get python to load json file

Tags: python, json

This is the error I keep getting

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is what the json data looks like:

```
{
    "TITLE": "Rome: The Punic Wars - The First Punic War - Extra History - #1",
    "CHANNEL_NAME": "Extra Credits",
    "NUMBER_OF_VIEWS": "3,954,083 views",
    "LIKES": "50,431",
    "DISLIKES": "887",
    "NUMBER_OF_SUBSCRIPTIONS": "2.37M",
    "HASH_TAGS": []
}
```

I've tried to modify the file to point of deleting all but the curly brackets, then even them to, but the error still happens.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import json

with open('C:/Users/longv/Desktop/data.json') as f:
    print('hello')
    data = json.load(f)
```

I also searched StackOverflow, but the discussions are so over my head I don't even understand, and it doesn't look like it'd work in my case anyway.

EDIT: This is a load of BS, because I used the online platform repl.it and this code worked fine.

Comment: Did you try with `json.loads()`?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of each element at a time to rule out an encoding issue with a particular part of the file?

Comment: your example object works fine for me, without errors

Comment: everything works also on my end, what python and json version did you used?

Comment: @bro I'm using python 3.6.0, for json version I have no idea. I only know import son. Let me try to update to the newest python version

Comment: @ bro after running through all the hoops of installing python 3.8.3, the same error still pops up

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to put the JSON file and the python code in the same directory.
Then try to write the following:

```
with open('yourjsonfile.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# then,if you want to print out the "TITLE" in your context
print(data['TITLE'])
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the JSON file have to be in the same directory when I can import a TXT or CSV file from a specified file path? I'm asking because I don't know where my python code is located.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the indentation. Indenting the `with` block like so might fix it:

```
import json

with open('C:/Users/longv/Desktop/data.json') as f:
    print('hello')
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: When I copied and paste the format is exactly what I already had